# Is there a way to toggle attributes from any columns in a react bootstrap table?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table react library in our project to create tables and would  like to now if there is a way to toggle attributes from the  "TableHeaderColumn"

For example in the sample code below I would like to add or remove the filter attribute if a Boolean is true or false.

```
    <BootstrapTable
        version="4"
        data={data}
        options={options}
        hover={true}
        pagination={true}
        search={true}
     >
         <TableHeaderColumn
             dataField="customerName"
             filter={{ type: "TextFilter", delay: 10 }}
             dataSort={true}
             caretRender={displaySortOrder}
         >
         Customer Name
         </TableHeaderColumn>

        <TableHeaderColumn
             dataField="Address"
             dataSort={true}
             caretRender={displaySortOrder}
         >
             Address                   
         </TableHeaderColumn>

    </BootstrapTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the filter in the table and manage the behavior with refs tags to apply or clean the filter.

First you need to define the classes to the filter:

```
const filterStyle = { display: 'none' };
const filterObj = { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000, style: filterStyle };
```

Then you can define the refs tag and the filter in the column:

```
<TableHeaderColumn ref="workshiftFilter" dataField="workshift" filter={filterObj} > ColumnTitle </TableHeaderColumn>
```

Finally you should use the ref in a function:

```
handleWorkshiftFilter = (selectedOption) => {
 switch (selectedOption.value) {
   case 'A':
     this.refs.workshiftFilter.applyFilter('A')
     break;
   case 'B':
     this.refs.workshiftFilter.applyFilter('B')
     break;
   case 'C':
     this.refs.workshiftFilter.applyFilter('C')
     break;
   default:
     this.refs.workshiftFilter.cleanFiltered();
     break;
 }
 return;
```

}

In this way you could active or inactive your filter in the column.

Regards